# Dagger2 not working in plain Java IntelliJ Gradle project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dagger-2, annotation-processing

I'm trying to get a simple **non-Android** Java project working with Dagger2 in IntelliJ (2016.3.3, not AndroidStudio) and Gradle (3.1), but nothing seems to get generated at all, I get no DaggerXXX classes output. Not sure if it's the Dagger annotation processing that doesn't work, the source set configuration in IntelliJ that's wrong, or something else. When building the project I get the following output:

```
build
|_classes
  |_main
    |_com
    | |_<test classes correctly built>
    |_generated
      |_<empty, but should contain generated Dagger classes?>
```

What I've done is:

- Configured the project to use annotation processing in the IntelliJ settings.
- Used the following config:

> ```
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         mavenCentral()
>         jcenter()
>         maven {
>             url("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
>         }
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.9"
>     }
> }
>
> apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt'
> apply plugin: 'java'
> apply plugin: 'idea'
>
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
>     apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
> }
>
> sourceSets {
>     main {
>         java {
>             srcDirs 'src/main/java'
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Test program:

> ```
> public class Test {
>
>     @Inject
>     TestPojo testPojo;
>
>     public static void main(String[] args){
>         <no generated Dagger component available for building>
>     }
>
> }
>
> @Component(modules = Module.class)
> public interface Component {
>
>     Pojo get();
>
> }
>
> @Module
> public class Module {
>
>     @Provides
>     public Pojo get(){
>         return new Pojo();
>     }
>
> }
>
> public class Pojo {}
> ```

**Update:**

It's working if I build the project through the command line and not through the IntelliJ gui. That points to the issue being within the IntelliJ environment or its Gradle integration somehow, rather than in the build script itself.

Comment: try adding apply plugin: 'application'
I have a dagger project I was messing with and in comparing it with yours, that's one difference I see.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't have any effect unfortunately. Thanks for the tip! It works however if I build it through the command line, see my updated question.